# How to use git flow without using release branch?

Tags: github, workflow, git-branch, git-flow

There are several branches available in **git flow**.
such as

- `feature/`
- `release/`
- `support/`
- `hotfix/`
- `bugfix/`

I do not need `release/` branch and want to merge `staging` branch (*a development branch*) directly to `master`. 
What is the best way to achieve this using **git flow**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be mandatory to make release branch for every release in **production** or your **master** branch

So There is no alternative way to do this.

Simply flow is as below:

1. Work on your `feature` branch
2. Finish work and merge your `feature` branch to staging
3. Make `release` branch from `staging`.
4. Add version and tag than merge it to `master` amd `staging` both.

I think this would be helpful for you.