# Skip Release branch in Gitflow TFS

Tags: git, tfs, git-flow

We are moving to Gitflow workflow with TFS and are using the Jacob Ehn plugin in Visual Studios. During our findings we have decided that a release branch is extra and increase the complexity. Can we implement Gitflow without creating a Release branch? We will perform all of the testing on Develop branch itself and then merge it into the Master branch from which we will make a build from theat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Gitflow is just a branching model for Git. It has attracted a lot of attention because it is very well suited to collaboration and scaling the development team.

It doesn't mean we have to follow this. And tfs also do not force you to use Gitflow when you are working on Git Source Control.

You could [adopt any Git branching strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-branching-guidance?view=azure-devops) and use your own's flow based on team's situation.

However, if you are following and using Gitflow. This would be **mandatory to make release branch** for every release in production or your master branch.

It's not able to skip release branch. You could take a look at this similar question: [How to use git flow without using release branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54924227/how-to-use-git-flow-without-using-release-branch)

Also suggest you kindly refer this clearly and detail tutorial about introducing GitFlow. Which help us understand how it works.